# Brownian Motion has generator $\frac{1}{2} f''$

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

For $t \geq 0$ let $P_{t}(x,\cdot)=N(x,t)$ be the transition kernels of a one dimensional Brownian Motion. Then $(\bar{P}_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ with

$
\bar{P}_{t}:C_{0}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C_{0}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}), f \mapsto (x \mapsto \int f(y) 
 P_{t}(x,dy))
$

is a $C_{0}$-semigroup. We define the generator L of $(\bar{P}_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ by

$
Lf=lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\bar{P}_{t}f-f}{t}
$

for $f \in D(L)=\{f \in C_{0}(\mathbb{R}):lim_{t \downarrow 0} \frac{\bar{P}_{t}f-f}{t} exists\}$. I already know that $C_{K}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is a core of L and that $Lf=\frac{1}{2}f''$ for $f \in C_{K}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}).$

**Question:** How can one proof that $(\bar{P}_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ has the generator $Lf=\frac{1}{2}f''$ with $D(L)=\{f \in C_{0}(\mathbb{R}):f'' \in C_{0}(\mathbb{R})\}$.

Comment: You can check this directly by hand using the fact that the transition density of the Brownian Motion is the Gaussian kernel $p_t(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}$, so long as you take a nice collection of functions $f$ to be the core of the domain of your generator. One thing to be careful about though. A generator isn't just an operator.  It is an operator together with its domain. It matters because the same "operator" can describe different stochastic processes if the domains are different.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know a book where I can find this?

Comment: Have you at least tried for a few minutes to do that calculation on you own before asking for book? It's not too hard at all.

Comment: Yes, i didn't succeed. Do you have some hints? I am new to this topic, so I want to have some book where I can learn something about the generator with the brownian motion as an example.

Comment: Apparently Chapter 7 , Theorem 2.5, Durrett's calculus might have a proof, from the deleted answer below. You can take a look.